# Laravel Passport Login (API)

Tags: laravel, token, laravel-passport, laravel-5.7

I tried to login using API with registered user, but I'm always get this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KquCs.png)
How i can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to simply run this command:

```
php artisan passport:client --personal
```

[Source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/passport-fails-to-create-the-personal-access-token)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create personal access client by typing the following command

php artisan passport:client

Follow this link for more information
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#managing-clients